# What are the use cases of next redux wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I'm trying to use the next js example with redux config . I came across two examples one with simple [with-redux](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux) config setup and the other with [with-redux-wrapper](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper) .

I read all the readme stuff and still didn't quite get it . What are the use cases for each of these examples ?

And most importantly what are the differences between using the simple with-redux config and using the latest with-redux-wrapper config for a next js project ?